# Converting Drupal Boost .htaccess to Nginx

Tags: nginx, .htaccess, drupal7

I'm trying to install [Boost](https://drupal.org/project/boost) module to work with nginx. As we know Boost does not generate nginx directives just like Apache.

Boost has the following directives for Apache's .htaccess:

```
  ### BOOST START ###

  # Allow for alt paths to be set via htaccess rules; allows for cached variants (future mobile support)
  RewriteRule .* - [E=boostpath:normal]

  # Caching for anonymous users
  # Skip boost IF not get request OR uri has wrong dir OR cookie is set OR request came from this server OR https request
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^(GET|HEAD)$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (^/(admin|cache|misc|modules|sites|system|openid|themes|node/add|comment/reply))|(/(edit|user|user/(login|password|register))$) [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} DRUPAL_UID [OR]
  RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
  RewriteRule .* - [S=3]

  # GZIP
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} !gzip
  RewriteRule .* - [S=1]
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/%{ENV:boostpath}/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}_%{QUERY_STRING}\.html -s
  RewriteRule .* cache/%{ENV:boostpath}/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}_%{QUERY_STRING}\.html [L,T=text/html,E=no-gzip:1]

  # NORMAL
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/%{ENV:boostpath}/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}_%{QUERY_STRING}\.html -s
  RewriteRule .* cache/%{ENV:boostpath}/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}_%{QUERY_STRING}\.html [L,T=text/html]

  ### BOOST END ###
```

I tried to convert the above code to nginx by using this [site](http://winginx.com/htaccess) to no avail. Here's the converted code that don't work:

```
# nginx configuration

location / {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /cache/$env_boostpath/$http_host$request_uri_$query_string\.html;
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /cache/$env_boostpath/$http_host$request_uri_$query_string\.html;
}
```

Can anyone help me please.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

nginx is not apache. You should be using `try_files`, not rewrites, for this sort of thing.

For instance, [this was ripped out](https://github.com/perusio/drupal-with-nginx/blob/D7/apps/drupal/drupal_boost.conf) of a very well done [sample Drupal nginx configuration](https://github.com/perusio/drupal-with-nginx):

```
    try_files /cache/normal/$host${uri}_${args}.html /cache/perm/$host${uri}_.css /cache/perm/$host${uri}_.js /cache/$host/0$uri.html /cache/$host/0${uri}/index.html @drupal;
```

Comment: I'm having trouble with perusio's configuration because I am using ispconfig 3. And I am lost with so many configuration. Can you please guide me for the optimal configuration of Boost for nginx?

Comment: I just did. You would be better off without ispconfig. :)

Comment: I tried `try_files` above but still it doesn't work. I can't work without ispconfig. All of my sites are already using it.